# Message Store supporting rollback?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Using wso2ei-6.4.0 I see it is possible to consume messaging messages (RabbitMQ) either by defining an inbound endpoint or defining a message store.

The required functionality is guaranteed delivery and message ordering. If we use the suggested [Guaranteed Delivery with Failover Message Store](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Guaranteed+Delivery+with+Failover+Message+Store+and+Scheduled+Failover+Message+Forwarding+Processor), we loose the message ordering (as the failed messages are store to the beginning of the queue).

My idea is leveraging JMS transactions. Can I use JMS transaction with the JMS message store or do I need to define a JMS Inbound Endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I must say, I haven't tried it with RabbitMQ. When I created a transactional consumer with ActiveMQ (JMS queue) there were two requirements:

- Use `call` with `blocking="true"` to forward the message
- Set the `SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY` property in case of a fault.
- (don't use `OUT_ONLY` and `HTTP_SC_ACCEPT` properties!)

Looking at the sourcecode I suspect that transactions should even work without setting any properties, see the 'startConsumer' function [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/master/components/inbound-endpoints/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/inbound/endpoint/protocol/rabbitmq/RabbitMQConnectionConsumer.java)